# Using plural when referring to cent and cents

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

What is the correct grammar when saying cent or cents?

Do you use plural when you are referring to more than 1?  For example, do you say I have *five hundred dollars and 36 cents* in the bank or *five hundred dollars and 36 "cent"*.

Comment: This question lacks evidence of research. It is liable to attract downvotes and closevotes. Please describe your efforts at research in the question.

Comment: Related: *["Here is my two cents" vs "Here are my two cents"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343641/here-is-my-two-cents-vs-here-are-my-two-cents)*

Comment: Sometimes singular form:  "a 50 cent coin"  just like "a ten foot pole" or "a three hour wait".

Answer (score 2):

Definitely cents, with the emphasis on the *s*.

If you want to use it as an adjective, just always make it singular to render it as a modifier.

And if you want it is a noun, you don't have to change the form of the word/s you have intended to state.

You can click the link here for more information: [CENTS, not "cent"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126034830/http://www.topix.com/forum/city/welch-wv/TSFBIHPPHBRQ8OLE3)

Comment: What kind of link is that? *"Unfortunately at this time we are unable to process international online transactions. Please keep in mind that under the official rules for Publishers Clearing House there are geographic limitations to entry into our promotions, contests and giveaways."*. In any case, are there users for whom this link is ***not*** (effectively) broken?

Comment: The OP will not respond: *"Last seen more than 9 years ago"*