# "Here is my two cents" vs "Here are my two cents"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, descriptive-grammar, style-manuals

Which of the following two phrases is correct, in the context of giving an opinion on a subject?

- Here **is** my two cents on subject X
- Here **are** my two cents on subject X

Most of what I found online was guesswork...

From *["Here is my two cents" vs "Here are my two cents"?](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic24834.html)*:

> I think 'my two cents' is an abbreviation of "two cents' worth". So, as you said, "Here is my two cents" would be better.

And...

> It's worth noting that money is often perceived as a unit anyway, so you'll see "cents" with a singular verb frequently.

Comment: This is interesting (does "here" change it up?) Please add any info you found on searching out the answer or it may be closed for lack of research.

Comment: In BrE (not completely certain about AmE), it should be ***is*** because "two cents" is semantically a singular element - effectively it's short for *my **contribution*** (which ***is** worth two cents*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think you might be correct. Now that I think through another example, you would say "Here is 100 dollars." and not "Here are 100 dollars", correct?  You are giving a sum of 100 dollars as a single action.

Comment: I've seen people use both but I believe that *"Here **is** my two cents"* is both more common and more correct, because, as @FumbleFingers says, it means your opinion, which is singular.  Also, I believe it's a contraction of "My two cent's worth (of thoughts)", which would also be singular.

Comment: I did find [Here **are** five dollars. Buy yourself a revolver and commit suicide](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22here+are+five+dollars+buy%22) on Google Books. But it does sound a bit weird to me. It's ***an*** amount of money, not five separate items.

Comment: Maybe there are five one dollar notes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd posit that the ***"here's..."*** version is preferable, on various grounds.

As the OP suggests, the implied meaning is "here's my two cents *worth*". In fact this idiom is likely derived from (or at least cognate to) the common British English expression:

> Here's my tuppenceworth

(Tuppence = 'two pennies'). https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuppence_worth#English https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tuppenceworth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctuppenceworth%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctuppenceworth%3B%2Cc0

Also "my two cents" is clearly a singular thing in this idiom (meaning 'my opinion'). By using ***is***, rather than ***are***, you avoid any ambiguity: it's clear that you're not referring to two individual 1c coins.

And - just from my own experience - I've heard variations on the "two cents" and the "tuppence" phrases many times, and it's always been with the **is** form. "That's my two cents" sounds fine,  "Those are my two cents" sounds very awkward, archaic and pedantic.

To sum up: yes, the standard laws of grammar would require the verb to agree in number with the object (in its literal sense), but with a common idiom like this, conventional usage ***defines*** the grammaticality.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my two cents on the subject.

---

Interestingly the ngram viewer doesn't find a single occurrence of **are my two cents**. The actual book search does however. Guess those books are not part of the corpus ngram is based on.

However there is a clear rising trend of **'s my two cents** (top four of all phrases ending in **my two cents**) and **here's my two cents**. ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+my+two+cents%2Cis+my+two+cents%2Care+my+two+cents%2Chere%27s+my+two+cents&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badd%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bget%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badded%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstick%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcontribute%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badding%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chere%20%27s%20my%20two%20cents%3B%2Cc0))

---

Of course the Google Ngram Viewer is not an explanation regarding why that singular version is highly preferred and the usage of is and it's contraction is on such a rise.

As you have already written in your question it's short for *two cents' worth* ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/two-cents-or-two-cents%27-worth?q=two+cents)) and as such the singular usage would be logical.

Comment: Sentences with *'s* contractions aren't always equivalent in acceptability to sentences with uncontracted *is.* "*There's*" is probably the most well-known example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take... the phrase "my two cents" really represents **my opinion**, which is singular. So the proper use is:

*Here is my two cents.*

(I.E. "Here is my opinion")

... and not: "Here are my two cents."